# Changing img's src by snippet/plugin

Tags: modx

I want to change empty img tags' sources to paths from TVs from the document. Next I want to display docs (with different images in TVs) by getResources. How to do this? Do I have to use PHP or is there better and faster way?

So <img> from document which have TV set to "\aaa\j.jpg" should be changed to <img src="\aaa\j.jpg">

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [filters from MODX](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Input+and+Output+Filters+%28Output+Modifiers%29). In your template:

```
<img src="[[*your_tv_name:notempty=`[[*your_tv_name]]`]]" />
```

This checks whether your TV is set and then outputs it. I would suggest you make your TV type URL (under input options) to make sure it's a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

Set you image TV to be of an "image" TV type, and it's output to be an image as well ~ that way you won't have empty image tags if the image TV is not populated. 
If you want a default image value for that TV, just set it in your TV setup preferences.

If I understand, you want that 'default' image is different for each resource? in which case we are going to need more info, like how you want to determine what the image is. But basically, 'yes' you will probably have to use some code - look at the bindings in the docs: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Bindings

Is the getResources part a second question? [you need to clarify your question somewhat]

Comment: I think that you don't understand me :)

I have documents with default-image chunk and I want to change all img  tags without src to &lt;img src="[[$default-image]]&gt;.

I can make default-image chunk with &lt;img src="..."&gt;, but I think about shortening it ;)